# Unable to load web application deployed to standalone GlassFish, when deployed via Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, glassfish

After importing [a sample struts project](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/hello-world-using-struts2.html) into Eclipse(version 2019-12 (4.14.0)), and installing the GlassFish Tools plugin, I have been able to do the following:
・build the maven project (created a maven build configuration, with maven goal 'clean install')
  → the output war file gets generated in the target folder
・Add the instance of glassfish situated independently on my local machine to Eclipse
・deploy the project to the server (right clicking project root in project explorer, and doing 'run on server', selecting previously added glassfish server)

However, when I try to load a url of the application in a browser, I just get a 404 error message.
I have checked that the application is infact deployed, by referring to  the GlassFish Console (http://localhost:4848/)
 I have double checked the url in use, with the context root field for the application on http://localhost:8080/
If I deploy the same war file manually, using the 'asadmin' command line utility, I can successfully load the expected page by specifying the same url.

When using both methods (commamd line, and Eclipse 'run on server') to deploy, the war file is the same.

Any ideas as to why I'm able to deploy in Eclipse, but just get 404 messages?
※Using both methods, the application context root is the same, as checked via the GlassFish Console.

Comment: The URL may be different from what you get from a manual deployment.  Check the administration console for which URL you should use.

Comment: I'm checking that, and it's the same either way.
The only difference I can find, is in the domain.xml file for Glassfish after deployment.
When done via Eclipse, the name attribute of <context-root> changes to the value of the artifactId in the pom file. In addition, an extra attribute 「directory-deployed="true"」is also present.

The value of the <module name> tag under application context-root, also changes to the Artifact ID value. The application context-root itself however remains constant.

Comment: If the context root changes, your URL changes as well so that explains what you see.  Change your url to reflect the actual context root.  The administration console may be able to link directly to your deployment if I recall correctly (been a while)